# Getting values from database with delay

Tags: front-end

I have a problem with getting custom meta after the post is submited on frontend.

I'm getting two custom fields with `get_post_meta($post_id, 'map_lat', true)` etc. When user submits the post, value gets updated and the page is reflashed. The problem is that, values are not yet updated in database, and when the page is loaded again, it received old data, so if user saves the page without reloading it before is saves the old values over again. Is there any way to delay getting data from database or slow down page reload?

I was also thinking about delaying action on button but I have no idea how to do it:

Action after pressing submit button:

```
$('#btn_check_insert_activity').click(function() {
    var dk = true;
    if (dk == true) {
        console.log('Submit create Activity !');
        $('#btn_insert_post_type_activity').click();
    }
});
```

EDIT:

Part to update the custom meta is:

```
if(class_exists('CodespacingProgressMap') && isset($_POST[CSPM_LATITUDE_FIELD], $_POST[CSPM_LONGITUDE_FIELD])){         
    $ProgressMapClass = CodespacingProgressMap::this();
    $ProgressMapClass->cspm_save_frontend_location(array(
        'post_id' => $post_id,
        'latitude' => esc_attr($_POST[str_replace(".",",",CSPM_LATITUDE_FIELD)]),
        'longitude' => esc_attr($_POST[str_replace(".",",",CSPM_LONGITUDE_FIELD)]),
        'post_type' => 'activity'
    )); 
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code you use to update the meta? Is this with Ajax?

Comment: @Nath I've updated the post :)

Comment: Okay so you are using a third-party plugin? If that is the case the support you will recieve here will probably be quite limited. And you may be better off asking the plugin developer.

Comment: @Nath Yes, but that's not the point. What the plugin does with this with the field is saving it with `update_post_meta($post_id, CSPM_LATITUDE_FIELD, $latitude);` right away. So I don't think it's plugin related. I just need to find the way to delay it for milliseconds :) When I overload form with some huge data, value loads normally.

Comment: Still as I am not familiar with this plugin and most people here probably wont be either. I'll just say this, normally when I update meta through an interface I would use ajax. And then if you need to excute another function after that but want to make sure the first function is complete you can use [when](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) to do that.